# C++ Doesn't append to the text file

Tags: c++, file, text, append

For some reason, the code below doesn't append the *user* to the *user.txt* file. It always ends up in the `if(file.fail())` structure.
Any idea on how to fix it? I tried closing and opening the same file again before writing the *user* to it. But that doesn't seem to work either.

```
   void users::userAdd()
    {
    std::string username;
    std::string function;
    std::string user;
    std::size_t found;
    std::string line;
    std::fstream myfile ("C:\\Users\\kk\\Desktop\\users.txt",  std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app);

    if (!myfile || !myfile.good())
    {
        std::cout << "could not open file!\n";
    }
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout<<"new username:";
        std::cin>>username;

        while (! myfile.eof())
        {
            getline (myfile,line);
            found = line.find(username);

            if (found != std::string::npos)
            {
                std::cout<<"User already exists"<<std::endl;
                return;
            }
        }
        std::cout<<"Function:";
        std::cin>>function;
        user = username+ " " + function;
        myfile << user;
        myfile.close();
    }
    if (myfile.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to append to file!\n";
    }
}
```

### Edit

I removed the `std::ios_base::append`and added a couple lines: (it works like I want it to)

```
    ...
    std::cout<<"functie:";
    std::cin>>functie;
    myfile.clear();
    myfile.seekg(0, myfile.end);
    user = "\n" + gebruikersnaam + " " + functie;
    myfile << user;
    myfile.close();
    ...
```

Comment: Call [`std::fstream::clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) after all input was read, before append writing to the file call [`std::fstream::seekg()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) to set the write position. Also note [`while (! myfile.eof())`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) raises some problems.

Comment: First, you open a file in append mode, which positions the file pointer past the end of the file. Then you try to read a line from it. What do you expect the `getline` to return?

Comment: Mmh, that's true dasblinkenlight. I didn't see that directly.
Thank you πάντα ῥεῖ and jotik for the solution. It works now. I'll post the solution under "EDIT:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not rewinding the file, i.e. repositioning the read/write pointer to the beginning of the file. Using `std::ios_base::app` means that the read/write pointer is position at the end of the file.

You should probably omit `std::ios_base::app`. This way your `while`-loop will read the whole file and effectively position the pointer to the end of the file before you append to it.

**See also:** [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670359/fstream-seekg-seekp-and-write).

PS: This looks to be a bug:

```
if (found != std::string::npos) {
    std::cout<<"User already exists"<<std::endl;
    return;
}
```

what if `username` is a substring of `line`?

Answer (score 0):

Put `myfile.tellg (0)` to start reading from the start of the file.