# reading/writing class objects to files in c++

Tags: c++, class, object, c++11, file-io

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Student{
private:
    char name[40];
    char grade;
    float marks;
public:
    void getdata();
    void display();
};

void Student::getdata(){
    char ch;
    cin.get(ch);
    cout<<"Enter name : ";
    cin.getline(name,40);
    cout<<"Enter grade : ";
    cin>>grade;
    cout<<"Enter marks : ";
    cin>>marks;
    cout<<"\n";
}

void Student::display(){
    cout<<"Name : "<<name<<"\t";
    cout<<"Grade : "<<grade<<"\t";
    cout<<"Marks : "<<marks<<"\t"<<"\n";
}

int main(){
    system("cls");
    Student arts[3];
    fstream f;
    f.open("stu.txt",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
    if(!f){
        cerr<<"Cannot open file !";
        return 1;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        arts[i].getdata();
        f.write((char*)&arts[i],sizeof(arts[i]));
    }
    f.seekg(0); //The question is about this statement;
    cout<<"The contents of stu.txt are shown below : \n";
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        f.read((char*)&arts[j],sizeof(arts[j]));
        arts[j].display();
    }
    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The above program reads and writes objects of Student from/to the file "stu.txt".
It runs fine. But it runs fine even if I switch off the fin.seekg(0) statement. I don't understand this part ? Are we not supposed to set the file pointer to the beginning of the file - before starting to read objects from the file(in the context of this particular program)?.

Comment: No it does not work fine, it's just that you don't check for errors when reading.

Comment: @Galik only one file pointer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670359/fstream-seekg-seekp-and-write

Comment: Try creating a new array to read into and see if it still appears to work.

Comment: @CashCow Thanks ! That makes it clear now !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are at the end of the file, the `read` method call will fail, thus the `Student` structures are left untouched (so you are just printing again the same structures which you left untouched after writing them to file).

Comment: Thanks, I understand now - I created a new array of objects and tried to switch off fin.seekg(0) - and it did print all garbage !