# Does stream::seekoff update the input sequence?

Tags: c++, stream, buffer, language-lawyer

In [[filebuf.virtuals]](http://eel.is/c++draft/filebuf.virtuals#13):

> ```
> pos_type seekoff(off_type off, ios_base::seekdir way,
>                  ios_base::openmode which
>                    = ios_base::in | ios_base::out) override;
> ```
>
> *Effects:* Let `width` denote `a_­codecvt.encoding()`. If `is_­open() == false`, or `off != 0 && width <= 0`, then the positioning operation fails. Otherwise, if `way != basic_­ios​::​cur` or `off != 0`, and if the last operation was output, then update the output sequence and write any unshift sequence. Next, seek to the new position: if `width > 0`, call `fseek(file, width * off, whence)`, otherwise call `fseek(file, 0, whence)`.

It does not mention that this function updates the input sequence. As a contrast, `seekpos` does update the input sequence:

> ```
> pos_type seekpos(pos_type sp,
>                  ios_base::openmode which
>                    = ios_base::in | ios_base::out) override;
> ```
>
> Alters the file position, if possible, to correspond to the position stored in `sp` (as described below). Altering the file position performs as follows:
>
> 1. if `(om & ios_­base​::​out) != 0`, then update the output sequence and write any unshift sequence;
> 2. set the file position to `sp` as if by a call to `fsetpos`;
> 3. if `(om & ios_­base​::​in) != 0`, then **update the input sequence**;

So is `seekoff` guaranteed to update the input sequence?

For a concrete example, consider:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::fstream f("test.txt"); // test.txt contains "test"
    char ch;
    f >> ch;
    f.rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0, std::ios_base::beg);
    f >> ch;
    std::cout << ch;
}
```

Is the program **guaranteed** to output `t`?

Answer (score 2):

I can see your point friend, and indeed this may be a source of some confusion not only for yourself.

**Short answer:**

Yes, `seekoff` will update the the input sequence just as `seekpos` will. Both `seekoff` and `seekpos` behave the same regarding which sequence is being updated by the call, input or output (or both).

**Long explanation**:

Not by way of convention alone, but according to the standard itself, the behavior of both `seekoff` and `seekpos` is defined to be dependent of the `ios_base::openmode which` argument. As can be seen in another class template, `stringbuf`, derived from the same parent as `filebuf`, [the override for `seekoff`](http://eel.is/c++draft/stringbuf.virtuals#9) explicitly states that for `(which & ios_­base​::​in) == ios_­base​::​in` **the call will position the input sequence**; for `(which & ios_­base​::​out) == ios_­base​::​out` **the call will position the output sequence**; for `(which & (ios_­base​::​in | ios_­base​::​out)) == (ios_­base​::​in | ios_­base​::​out)` and `way ==` either `ios_­base​::​beg` or `ios_­base​::​end` **the call will position both the input and the output sequences.**

But when working directly in front of the standard, one need not expect things to just present themselves. See here under the parent class [`streambuf`](http://eel.is/c++draft/streambuf.virt.buffer#3):

> ```
> pos_type seekoff(off_type off, ios_base::seekdir way,
>                  ios_base::openmode which
>                    = ios_base::in | ios_base::out) override;
> ```
>
> *Effects:* Alters the stream positions within one or more of the controlled sequences in a way that **is defined separately for each class derived** from `basic_­streambuf` ...

So, by looking more carefully in the standard for [the quote you have provided yourself regarding `seekpos` of `filebuf`](http://eel.is/c++draft/filebuf.virtuals#16):

> ```
> pos_type seekpos(pos_type sp,
>                  ios_base::openmode which
>                    = ios_base::in | ios_base::out) override;
> ```
>
> Alters the file position, if possible, to correspond to the position stored in `sp` (as described below). Altering the file position performs as follows:
>
> 1. if `(om & ios_­base​::​out) != 0`, then update the output sequence and write any unshift sequence;
> 2. set the file position to `sp` as if by a call to `fsetpos`;
> 3. if `(om & ios_­base​::​in) != 0`, then update the input sequence;

the following line says:

> **where `om` is the open mode passed to the last call to open().** ...

So this means that you cannot specify in the call itself which sequence you want to update. As in, the standard here says that the implementation should **plainly ignore (!)** the `om` argument.

Another bit we need not miss is in the quote you have provided regarding `seekoff`, where it says:

> Next, seek to the new position: if `width > 0`, **call `fseek(file, width * off, whence)`**, otherwise call **`fseek(file, 0, whence)`**.

So underlying it's just a call to [`fseek`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fseek). But on which particular FILE object? Are there separate ones for input and output? I believe the answer we're looking for appears in spec under [filebuf](http://eel.is/c++draft/filebuf#3):

> § 27.9.1.1
>
> 1. The class basic_filebuf associates both the input sequence and the
>      output sequence with a file.
> 2. The restrictions on reading and writing a sequence controlled by an object of class 
>      basic_filebuf are the same as for reading and writing with the Standard C library 
>      FILEs.
> 3. In particular:
>
>    - If the file is not open for reading the input sequence cannot be read.
>    - If the file is not open for writing the output sequence cannot be written.
>    - **A joint file position is maintained for both the input sequence and the output sequence.**

As in, both `seekoff` and `seekpos` behaves the same regarding which sequence is being updated by the call, input or output (or both), and it is determined only by what was passed to `open()`.

Also, just encountered this from about 5 years ago I see: [fstream seekg(), seekp(), and write()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670359/fstream-seekg-seekp-and-write/15673510)

**Edit, for further clarification:**

Note the spec for `seekoff` says:

> if the last operation was output, then update the output sequence and
>   *write any unshift sequence.*

`seekpos` also says:

> update the output sequence and write any unshift sequence;

It is [the remarks section for `seekoff`](http://eel.is/c++draft/filebuf#virtuals-14) that defines what “Write any unshift sequence” means. And as such it should be equivalent for both methods. But then both specify further: `seekoff` says it calls `fseek` and `seekpos` says it calls `fsetpos` (identical to `fseek` in this regard).

The reason for this, and for even mentioning the *last operation was output* bit, is found when considering that point 2 from section § 27.9.1.1 brought above is explained here in the C11 standard, ISO/IEC 9899:2011:

> #### §7.21.5.3 The `fopen` function
>
> ¶7 When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third character in the
>   above list of mode argument values), both input and output may be performed on the
>   associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an
>   intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`,
>   `fsetpos`, or `rewind`), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an
>   intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file.

So to answer your comment below, whether `seekoff` will update the input sequence is regardless of whether the last operation was input. If the last operation wasn't input, then there's the technicality with the *unshift sequence* discussed above. But part of the idea for the whole `stream` classes is to encapsulate i/o in a way that doesn't bother you with such maintenance chores.

Comment: So if the last operation was input, why will `seekoff` for filebuf update the input sequence? The input sequence is a buffer, which is independent of the file position and it should be updated to sync with the file position. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: @xskxzr So the class template std::basic_filebuf holds a single file position. There is no independent tracking of input and output positions in this case, only a restriction pertaining to whether you are permitted to read or write or both. I'll edit the answer to better reflect this point and add some explanation in the context of your comment.

Comment: `fseek`/`fsetpos` only changes the underlying file position, which does not affect the C++ stream buffer (input sequence), is this right?

Comment: @xskxzr Yes you are correct. And by the spec itself some details are implementation dependent. For example see here: http://eel.is/c++draft/filebuf#virtuals-19. And this is from cppreference.com: "`sync()` or its equivalent is implicitly called by `close()`, `seekoff()`, and `seekpos()` and explicitly called by `std::basic_streambuf::pubsync()`". See here at the *Notes* section: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/sync.

Comment: Yes, if "`sync()` or its equivalent is implicitly called by `close()`, `seekoff()`, and `seekpos()`", everything is fine. But I cannot find any support in the standard for this assertion. This is what exactly I asked.

Comment: @xskxzr Just to be clear, are you considering the possibility that for example `istream:seekg` on an `fstream`/`ifstream` might not sync the input sequence, even though it is the main thing for it to do? The standard says `seekg` is implemented in terms of `seekoff`: http://eel.is/c++draft/istream.unformatted#43

Comment: Yes, I think it should be synced but I cannot find an evidence in the specification.

Comment: For the avid reader, here are two official issues, not directly related to the OP but just might shed some light: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#171, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2473

Comment: @xskxzr There is no evidence in the specification even for guaranteeing the mere existence of stream buffers (for input/output sequences) in the implementation. See here for example, when trying to manually provide them: http://eel.is/c++draft/filebuf#virtuals-12. It says for `setbuf`: "... the results are implementation-defined." But again, it does say that "a joint file position is maintained ... [for both sequences]": http://eel.is/c++draft/filebuf#3.3. Is this not enough evidence to claim that an implementation must keep both sequences in sync with the file pointer?

Comment: But why does `seekpos` explicitly say "update the input sequence" while `seekoff` does not? This seems inconsistent.

Comment: @xskxzr Such inconsistency in the wording of the standard may well be the case, but I think you'll agree the OP wasn't directly about the inconsistency as much as it was trying to figure out whether updating of the input sequence is guaranteed or not.

Comment: I don't think "a joint file position is maintained ... [for both sequences]" is an evidence. I think this sentence is saying the input sequence and the output sequence share the same file pointer, rather than synchronization. I mentioned that inconsistency since if the synchronization is guaranteed by "a joint file position is maintained ... [for both sequences]", then it is unreasonable to say "update the input sequence" again.

Comment: @xskxzr So if the sentence is saying the sequences share the same file pointer, and you acknowledge that intermediate buffers aren't necessitated by the spec, then what is the meaning of not being synchronized under these assertions? As in, the lack of evidence for existence of stream buffers is the further evidence for the synchronization, and thus it follows that "update the input sequence" is a mere inconsistency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177587/discussion-between-skepticalempiricist-and-xskxzr).